# Obtener cuerpo de notificacion sin interactuar con ella cuando la app está en segundo plano

Tags: java, android-studio, app, firebase-messaging

Estoy desarrollando una app de notificaciones con fierebase que genera una notificacion cuando pulso un boton en una web.

La finalidad de esta app , es tener un log de a que hora y día se ha pulsado ese botón, y el usuario que lo pulsó.
Para ello , cuando la app esta en primer plano,el método onMessageRecived() de firebase me obtiene el cuerpo de la notificación cuando llega guardando dicha información en una db interna.
Pero cuando la app está en segundo plano, la única forma de obtener el cuerpo del mensaje es interactuando con el y entonces , poder guardarlo en la db , pero el problema aquí , es que si recibo mas de una notificación , para poder guardar todos los mensajes tengo que interactuar uno por uno , y si el usuario borra la notificación, tampoco se podrá guardar ya que no existe.

¿Alguna idea de como puedo llevar a cabo este proyecto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando se toca el botón además de mandar la notificación, guarda el contenido del mensaje en una base de datos.

Cuando la app pase de estar en segundo plano a primer plano, haz una consulta al servidor para descargar las actualizaciones que pudieran estar faltando.

Esta consulta debiera buscar en la base de datos y devolverle la información a la app.

Comment: Gracias Juan! Esa era mi última opción , pero se acaba de convertir en la única !